# Fastest point-in-polygon solution with billions of points over thousands of polygons

Tags: postgis, performance, point-in-polygon

Problem definition is quite simple: I need to achieve point-in-polygon detection for:

- billions of lat/lon points
- over thousands of polygons

I need to be able, for every point, to determine if it is in one or several of the polygons available (in the thousands). Currently we are using PostGIS with `ST_Contains` but the whole things needs 3 good entire days (roughly 80 hours) to compute from start to finish.

Is there any solution (free or not) that would offer significant speed improvement for this workload over PostGIS? It can be anything from an analytical database (Exasol is one example that comes to mind, however although hugely faster than Postgres as a database, I'm not sure if it's any faster for geographical computations) to a dedicated C/C++/Rust piece of code.

Comment: sub divide the polygons

Comment: @IanTurton triangles? it's gonna be a lot of them... but it also means we can compute them all at once on a GPU, if we write a bit of custom CUDA code

Comment: Google's BigQuery can run a spatial join like this in a few minutes, with the same SQL you are using in PostGIS. Not free, but it  handles much larger datasets than that.

Comment: if bigquery can do it in minutes, then I believe CUDA can do it in seconds? given we put that onto 16 parallelized GPUs?

Comment: Postgis has a st_subdivide function,

Comment: And I would ignore the worry about rounding errors (no one cares about nanometers)

Comment: @Jivan sure, I guess it depends on where this implementation is going and how much of your time you want to invest in it. Loading the data into BQ and running the same query you are using in Postgres would be the lowest level of effort.

Comment: The other technique you can use to do something like this quicky is to index the polygons using something like geohashes or S2 geometries. That allows you to run a point in polygon query without spatial tools since the intersection query is effective just some bit math.

Comment: @IanTurton sorry but I fail to see how the question you linked answers this question. The linked question is about tuning PostGIS, and my question is about finding a different solution apart from PostGIS. Could you undo the duplicate and reopen the question please?

Comment: did you try to use postgis properly to get a solution?

Comment: @IanTurton this is irrelevant — I'm asking for a solution _other than_ PostGIS, so whether I tried with PostGIS or not is not relevant. You don't know the reasons why we need to get away from PostGIS (performance is only one of the factors, but there are many others).

Comment: @Jivan, It occurs to me that if the points and polygons are defined in a half portion of the Earth they can be converted to a gnomonic projected system, in which the geodesic lines are straight lines, and apply the function on geometries instead of geographies.

Comment: Splitting complex polygons with many vertices into smaller ones with less vertices is a relevant approach everywhere so consider PostGIS and ST_Subdivide as an example. Read a study with SpatiaLite http://www.gaia-gis.it/spatialite-3.0.0-BETA1/WorldBorders.pdf

Comment: @user30184 it's a cool idea but doesn't get us anywhere near the kind of speed we need unfortunately

Comment: Should your point really be contained by your polygon or `ST_intersects` is acceptable ? `ST_intersects` is faster than `ST_contains`.

Comment: Please define your environment. I did not suggest you to use  SpatiaLite but the method with simple polygons and tight spatial index. Or do you have evidense that the method is too slow? What is the speed that you need in some exact numbers?

Comment: @user30184 right, I didn't understand it like that — pretty agnostic to the environment, but the method I'm thinking of and have been trying works by 1. drawing bounding boxes around polygons to filter out the obvious non-matches, then 2. use the ray casting method (first on edge's bounding boxes to weed out obvious negatives once again for ray-casting, then checking actual intersections for the rest) — we're starting to get to very, very fast results compared to anything we've seen before

Comment: Sounds interesting. This one is quite fast as well https://youtu.be/_r4IqjGqGEY but the methods are not open.

Comment: Raster operations are sometimes much faster than playing with geometries. If you could convert your polygons into a raster in a clever way you migh be able to do point-in-polygon check by reading the pixel value. You should use binary encoding: first polygon=1, next=2, then 4, 8 and so on. Increase the value for overlapping polygons. If the pixel value is 10 you know that it comes from 2+8.

Comment: Do you need to determine *which* polygon is hit?

Comment: @CL this is a very good question — the answer is yes in this particular case

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need some kind of precomputed index structure.

In this case, a [grid](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Grid_(spatial_index)) might be useful. They are usually not used for general-purpose applications because it would be hard to choose the proper grid cell size, but your polygons should have known characteristics.

First, choose a fixed grid. For each grid cell, store two lists: polygons that completely cover the grid cell, and polygons that partically cover the grid cell. Make the grid cells small enough so that almost all of them are completely inside or outside all polygons.

To check a point, compute the grid cell number from its coordinates, and then read that cell's lists. You need to do raycasting only for partially covered cells (and for complex polygons, it is useful to precompute the intersection with the cell).

You need to write some code yourself, but at least the initial computation of the grid index can be done with PostGIS.

Comment: Brilliant man. Bravo.